# Java Script fileinput default value

Tags: javascript, file-io

I know that I cannot set fileinput (input type="file" id="fileinput") value due to security reasons, but can I set a default value inside open file window so after clicking Browse... the user have to click only Open to proceed ? I want to do this to make my application as easy as possible. Computer skills of some users are very limited.

Comment: How can you know the path of the desired file in your clients' computers? Can you read minds or something? :)

Comment: It's a program that we use at work, before it can be used, the one specific file must be loaded, but some guys have troubles even with that